# slider revolution - text elements overlapping

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

Been using Slider Revolution on WordPress recently for a new client and having one big issue that I cannot find an answer to.

**SITUATION**
- I have 2 text elements, a Title text element and a Description text element (one above the other - vertically stacked)
- They have been manually placed to be aligned-left inside the slider area.
- I have them with a fixed width so they only cover the left side of the slider panel
- I have them set for auto-wrap so words do not get cut off and the test will drop to another line if needed.

**PROBLEM**
With this configuration, if the Title text element is too long (too many words) it will dynamically expand vertically (drop down lines) and cover up or overlap the description text element box below it.

**SOLUTION**
I would like to find a way to "link" or "hook" these 2 elements together (stacked one on top of the other with little space) so they do not overlap and the top element will automatically push down the 2nd text element box. Is it an html issue? a z-index issue? a placement process issue?

In the image I provided, you can see the difference between a 1, 2 & 3 line TITLE, and how the space between them is fixed.  **HOW DO I GET IT TO BE DYNAMIC?**  I apologize if this has been answered before, but I have searched for hours and cannot find an answer.  Maybe I am searching with the wrong keywords.

[slider-revolution-examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISSD9.jpg)

Comment: why not simply make them one element, in side this element you have the title and the description and you won't have any issue

Comment: Sorry, forgot basics...  wordPress v4.8.2
Avada theme v5.2.2
Revolution Slider v5.4.6 
Hosted in Linux (Dreamhost)

Comment: Holy Crap, Temani.  I never thought if that.  I tested and it seems to work.  Thanks so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common situation with Revolution Slider when we use different text elements since they will be different layers and used with position:absolute.

The best solution for this is to merge all the text elements inside one element using basic HTML and style them as needed inside this element. Like this we only have one element used with position:absolute and inside it we have well formed HTML.